# Special badges for winning competitions?

Tags: feature-request, badges

At timely intervals gaming.stackexchange launch competitions. Usually around the time of a highly expected video game release. My thought was that the winners of those competitions should get a badge showing which competitions they won.

One example could be referring back to the Diablo 3 competition:
http://diablo3acts.com/

Badge example:
Diablo 3 Act 1 normal winner
or
Diablo 3 competition winner
or
Competition winner

Comment: HAT DASH BADGES. I WANT BADGES FOR MY HAAAAAAAATS.

Comment: Who needs badges? Just bring back Hat Dash! And make it permanent! Really though, +1'd. =D

Comment: @lesspop +2,000

Answer (score 9):

One thing that stifles these kinds of requests is the fact that badges—in their current implementation—are rolled out to the entire network of Stack Exchange sites. So asking for Arqade-specific badges results in one of two scenarios:

- Badges rolled out to 80+ sites that don't make a lick of sense on those sites
- An overhaul of the badge system to support site-specific badges

Both are... less than ideal from a user and developer standpoint, respectively, so these types of requests are at best ignored and usually denied.

Rather than having contest-specific badges, what about having general contest participation badges? These would apply to any site that runs contests and promotions, which these days is a whole lot of them.

Something like:

- Bronze badge: participated in one site-wide contest or promotion
- Silver badge: participated in (5|10) site-wide contests or promotions
- Gold badge: won a prize in a site-wide contest or promotion

What those badges should be called is left as an exercise for the reader, as I haven't a clue.

Comment: I think the idea of badges for certain levels of participation is a good one. I'm not so sure about a gold badge for winning. Like rep, badges are designed to encourage behaviors that benefit the site. But many of these contests have a large element of luck involved in determining the actual winners. I don't think we should give out gold badges (or any) for winning the dice roll.

Answer (score -1):

You're suggesting badges for winner of RND basically, since not everyone who **qualified** for an Act got a prize for it. As such, voting against your idea.

I would be neutral if it was amended to people who met qualifications or something not dependent on coin tossing. e.g. 'D3-Act4' would be for the 10+ who qualified for act 4 and not only those who won.

Don't particularly care either way about such a badge, but I dislike the idea of having one you can't possibly earn except thru luck.

Comment: I agree with you. It would then be for everyone that qualified or?

Comment: @Anders: Yes - my post was a bit unclear, updated it now.